# Npgsql parametrized statement

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql, npgsql

Does the latest version of [`Npgsql`](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/index.html) for `PostgreSQL` support parametrized statement ? If yes what is its form in C#
?

Comment: As the user manual contains [sections titled "Using parameters in a query" and "Using prepared statements"](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) (with an example) I'm not sure what you're asking here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html

and

http://www.npgsql.org/doc/3.0/

Comment: Both links are broken, this answer is outdated.